# Switch dimensions of 1D ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 'row' vector cast as a numpy ndarray. I would simply like to make it a 'column' vector (I don't care too much about the type as long as it is compatible with matplotlib). Here is an example of what I'm trying:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ndarray(shape=(1,4), dtype=float, order='F')
print(a.shape)
a.T #I think this performs the transpose?
print(a.shape)
```

The output looks like this:

```
(1, 4)
(1, 4)
```

I was hoping to get:

```
(1, 4)
(4, 1)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have seen that the transpose in numpy doesn't do anything to a 1D array. But is this a 1D array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transposing an array does not happen in place. Writing `a.T` creates a view of the transpose of the array `a`, but this view is then lost immediately since no variable is assigned to it. `a` remains unchanged.

You need to write `a = a.T` to bind the name `a` to the transpose:

```
>>> a = a.T
>>> a.shape
(4, 1)
```

In your example `a` is indeed a 2D array. Transposing a 1D array (with shape `(n,)`) does not change that array at all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want or need the singular dimension, unless you are trying to force a broadcasting operation.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

> You can treat rank-1 arrays as either row or column vectors. `dot(A,v)`
> treats `v` as a column vector, while `dot(v,A)` treats `v` as a row vector.
> This can save you having to type a lot of transposes.

Answer (score 0):

you can alter the shape 'in place' which will be the same as a.T for (1,4) but see the comment by Mr E whether it's needed. i.e.

```
...
print(a.shape)
a.shape = (4, 1)
print(a.shape)
```